# how to make angularjs website to load faster

Tags: angularjs, html

**I am developing a site ,in which front-end is made with Angularjs **

Site name is http://limokit.com/limolog but the problem is that , it take minimum 30 seconds to open the site page on browser. How to reduce this loading time?

we  used `ngRoute` to change the states , but do not getting the result which we wanted to achieve . We also converted all html and js as minified one but it is also not effecting the loading issue for first time.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like you're loading individual js and css file separately. This can slow down the loading of the page greatly especially on slower connections. The common optimization to do here is to group all js files and css files together and serve one single js and one single css file on production. I don't know what you're using to serve the JS/CSS files but I use [compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Django.

Also, to further debug this problem, it helps if you look at the network requests that your page is doing on page load in the Chrome inspector. You can glean a lot of information by seeing where your bottlenecks are on page load.

Answer (score 0):

In your site you're having 63 requests and around 3MB size (uncached).

As mentioned in the other answer package everything in bundles. E.g. vendor.bundle.js, bundle.js and bundle.css and also minify these bundles.

I would use [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) or gulp for bundling.

For debugging you can look in the browser console networking tab at the lower right in Firefox you can see a link to load time statistics and also get a info about caching.

The following screenshot shows statistics to your site (left with cache, right uncached).
[image: screenshot].

Comment: so what is your suggestion how can i overcome my loading problem

Answer (score -3):

Ditch all frameworks and libraries such as Angular and Jquery and use JSvanilla. Plain javascript is much faster to run(around 160x according to many resources i read..i also know that from my own experience).
Frameworks makes your site crawl.

Comment: It is like recommending somebody to use assembler because his C++ program is slow. There is no issue with any of these framework if they are used correctly.

Comment: When you add library-javascript actually needs to garbage collect everything and also execute the code from the library in order to run your code. What do you think is faster ? 5 lines of code or 15 lines? I also think you made the wrong comparison of assembly and c

Comment: What you say is true, but nobody is willing to make vanillajs whereas there are incredibly productive tools like angular or react, in the same way that nobody is willing to develop in assembler whereas you can develop in c# on a large framework. Every body knows that we always pay with performances what we gain 100 times in productivity, simplicity and maintainability. If they are well used, the lack of performance of any framework will never be visible in 95% of use cases.